# Как получить id input vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<input id="surname" v-model="name">

<script>
data(){
   name: 'some name'
}
methods:{
  getName(){
      console.log(this.name)
  }
}
</script>
```

Как получить id элемента input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете к вашему input добавить атрибут ref, и в скрипте производить нужные манипуляции, пример ниже:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: ''
  },
  methods:{
    getNameId(){
        console.log(this.$refs.textName.id);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<htmL>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
       <input id="surname" ref="textName" v-model="message">
       <button @click="getNameId">test</button>
     </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"> 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: подскажите, почему в модальном окне не получается получить значение id ?

Comment: А модалка у вас является другим компонентом? Или в рамках одного?